# 1980's story with 5 alien species including Ballerinas in which a man's body parts are replaced by acrylic

Tags: story-identification, aliens

A man is running from aliens. There are Five species now on earth. One race is very tall and graceful, called Ballerinas. In one scene, a girl broke and stretched her bones to be like them. In another scene, as the man is running out of a church he says "Didn't I tell you? They're allergic to WD-40!" He gets caught and vivisected, a piece at a time, by the Alien bad guys. He's found afterward with all body parts replaced by acrylic. Also he crashed through the human Ballerina wanna-be, breaking her in half and killing her. The story is probably from the 1980's.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Can you expand or clarify the part about "body parts replaced by acrylic"?

Comment: By "old" I guess yo mean like the 1930s?

Comment: @Joe L. Yes, it would seem that by the end of the story, WD-40 guy was caught and vivisected, a piece at a time by Alien bad guys, Also he crashed through the human Ballerina wanna-be, breaking her in half and killing her.The story is More like 1980's - thanks 4 asking.

Comment: Gah, I know I've read this description somewhere (the Ballerina part at least) but I cannot place it for the life of me.